# noglob function then use ls with param?

Tags: zsh

I just want to pass a glob through and then use it against ls directly.  The simplest example would be:

```sh
test() { ls -d ~/$1 }
alias test="noglob test"
test D*
```

If I simply run `ls D` in my home directory: it outputs three files.  but if I run the snippet provided, I get `"/Users/jubi/D*": No such file or directory`. What should I be doing?  thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The authoritative and complete documentation of Zsh expansion mechanism is located at http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html.

Here's the reason your version doesn't work:

> If a word contains an **unquoted instance** of one of the characters ‘*’, ‘(’, ‘|’, ‘<’, ‘[’, or ‘?’, it is regarded as a pattern for filename generation, unless the GLOB option is unset.

emphasis mine. Your glob operator, generated by parameter expansion, isn't considered unquoted.

You need the `GLOB_SUBST` option to evaluate the parameter expansion result as a glob pattern. a `setopt globsubst`, `unsetopt globsubst` pair works, of course, but the easiest way is to use the following pattern specifically for this purpose:

> `${~spec}`
>
> Turn on the GLOB_SUBST option for the evaluation of spec; if the ‘~’ is doubled, turn it off. When this option is set, the string resulting from the expansion will be interpreted as a pattern anywhere that is possible, such as in filename expansion and filename generation and pattern-matching contexts like the right hand side of the ‘=’ and ‘!=’ operators in conditions.
>
> In nested substitutions, note that the effect of the ~ applies to the result of the current level of substitution. A surrounding pattern operation on the result may cancel it. Hence, for example, if the parameter foo is set to `*`, `${~foo//\*/*.c}` is substituted by the pattern `*.c`, which may be expanded by filename generation, but `${${~foo}//\*/*.c}` substitutes to the string `*.c`, which will not be further expanded.

So:

```
t () { ls -d ~/${~1} }
alias t="noglob t"
```

By the way, `test` is a POSIX shell builtin (aka `[`). Don't shadow it.

Comment: Thanks!  All those details are a lot more enlightening than just the syntax.  Appreciate it

Comment: @JustinBishop No problem, you can accept the answer so the question doesn't stay in the unanswered queue.